# Get specific text in <a> of datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I have a pagination button structure like below, they are constructed by [DataTable](https://datatables.net/). How can I get the text between the `<a>` tag? Or can I add `id` into these tag

```
    <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0" id="test_previous">
        <a href="#">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0" id="test_next">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to do this:

```
var newText = $('.paginate_button a').text();
console.log(text);
```

And it gave me:
Prev123Next

Comment: The result you get is from all the <a> values combined. if you need to get value from specific <a>, like first <a>, either you can add an ID value as you suggested, or you can use css selectors `var newText = $('.paginate_button a:nth-child(1)').text();`

Comment: Thanks @Vishwa. But then I want to do something like, click on button 1, alert "You clicked button 1", click button 2, alert "You clicked button 2",.... I would use a loop to do this?

Comment: using a loop would be a bad idea, you can use jQuery's on click to accomplish that but again you should use unique identifier, which will make your code less painful to see, read and debug. if you're okay with that, then I'll write up both into an answer

Comment: This structure is from DataTable, I know how to add CSS into it, but don't know how to add id in each tag, and I don't know if DataTable support id adding.It would be nice to see your answer :D

Comment: Obsidian Age had provided a good answer below, and you can use same method to select the element and use jQuery onclick with that. Ex: 

`var btn1 = $('.paginate_button a').first();`

`btn1.on( "click", function() {
  alert("You clicked button 1");
});`

Comment: @Vishwa, I tried Age's answer, and it worked perfectly.....for one button. However, when I have more than 100 buttons, that would be a real pain to create 100 events for them

Comment: there may be workarounds but those will probably mess up your code. anyway, one solution would be, 
`$('#btn1, #btn2').click(function () {
   if (this.id == 'btn1') {
      alert('button 1 clicked');
   }
   else if (this.id == 'btn2') {
      alert('button 2 clicked');
   }
});` **note:** you can use switch statements which would be easier than if, else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to get the text of clicked  tag, right?

Then try this code

```
$('body').on('click', '.paginate_button a', function(e){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaimin, your answer helps me a lot. In my case, it worked :D

Answer (score 2):

`$('.paginate_button a')` returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of **each** of the elements which match the selection criteria. In this example, every `<a>` element has a parent `.paginate_button` element, so each element is matched.

If you want to select a **specific** one, you can simply reference the index of the NodeList (and make use of `.innerText` instead of `.text())`:

```js
var newText = $('.paginate_button a')[0].innerText;
console.log(newText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0" id="test_previous">
    <a href="#">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0" id="test_next">
    <a href="#">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can make use of selectors such as **[`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)** to target individual results:

```js
var newText = $('.paginate_button a').first().text();
console.log(newText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0" id="test_previous">
    <a href="#">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0">
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="test" tabindex="0" id="test_next">
    <a href="#">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Age for your great help. And when I want to, let's say, when I click on button 1, it will alert "You've just clicked button 1", when click on button 2, alert "You've just clicked button 2", I would use a loop to do this?

Comment: Well it depends on exactly what you want to do. You'll certainly want to attach a click event handler, which can be done in JavaScript with `.addEventListener()`, or in jQuery with `.on('click', function() {} )`. Having said that, you'll likely be able to make use of jQuery's `.each()` to loop over the elements, depending on desired results.

Comment: I will try to implement this, thanks Age. BTW, I can't tag you and Idk why :D

Comment: You need to tag the `O` rather than the `A`, and you need to prepend the `@` symbol. But as it's my answer, I get the notification anyway. Hopefully it helps; if the answer does indeed answer the question, don't forget to mark it as accepted :)